# C# Empty WebClient Downloadstring

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to download the html string of a website. The website has te following url:

```
https://www.gastrobern.ch/de/service/aus-weiterbildung/wirtekurs/234/?oid=1937&lang=de
```

First I tried to do a simple WebClient Request:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
string websitenstring = "";
websitenstring = wc.DownloadString("http://www.gastrosg.ch/default.asp?id=3020000&siteid=1&langid=de");
```

But, the websiteString was empty. Then, I read in some posts, that I have to send some additional headerinformations :

```
var wc = new WebClient();
string websitenstring = "";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip, deflate, br";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage] = "de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "max-age=0";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Host] = "www.gastrobern.ch";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Upgrade] = "www.gastrobern.ch";
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36";

websitenstring = wc.DownloadString("https://www.gastrobern.ch/de/service/aus-weiterbildung/wirtekurs/234/?oid=1937&lang=de");
```

I tried this, but no answer. Then, I also tried to set some cookies:

```
wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie,
          "CFID=10609582;" +
          "CFTOKEN=32721418;" +
          "_ga=GA1.2.37" +
          "_ga=GA1.2.379124242.1539000256;" +
          "_gid=GA1.2.358798732.1539000256;" +
          "_dc_gtm_UA-1237799-1=1;");
```

But this also didn't work. I also found out, that the Browser is somehow doing multiple requests, and my C-Sharp Application is just doing one and showing the first response headers. 
[image]

But I don't know how I can make a following up request.  I'm thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `HttpClient` instead

Here is an Example On how to use it

```
public async static Task<string> GetString(string url)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    // Way around to avoid Deadlock
    HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

To call this Method

```
string dataFromServer = GetString("https://www.gastrobern.ch/de/service/aus-weiterbildung/wirtekurs/234/?oid=1937&lang=de").Result;
```

I checked Here `dataFromServer` has HTML content to that page